# Upgrade from Android L to Android 5

Tags: nexus-5

I rooted my nexus 5 and upgrade the developer images of Android L (build number LPV79) back in June or July. Now. I'm waiting for Android 5 OTA. Will I be getting it? How can I check when it will come? All my apps updated to Android 5 so they are not working and crushing because they are not compatible. And I'm not getting any support from Google / Android. Who can help me?

Answer (score 2):

There is no OTA update from the developer preview to the official release. You have to download the release version and flash it using `fastboot`.

Answer (score 0):

theres the official OTA updates knocking around online, but just 4.4 update to 5.0. you will need the stock "locked" bootloader with kitkat for it go ahead and you need to sideload it via adb. not sure if you can wipe the rom and install it fresh but there is the official full rom from the dev sites anyway. mine took an hour from start to finish from 4.4 offical to 5.0 OTA. all apps updated and works great. I never jumped onto the pre release as i wasn't desperate for it. I have no critical apps and all mine use current APIs anyway.

sorry if you already know this but im sure at some point this will help someone :)

OTA ROM nexus 5:
http://android.clients.google.com/packages/ota/google_hammerhead/c1a33561be84a8a6a7d5a4c8e3463c4db9352ce6.signed-hammerhead-LRX21O-from-KTU84P.c1a33561.zip

FULL ROM
https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images